# CUPS-PDF is very slow

Tags: linux, pdf, cups

I'm using CUPS-PDF printer to produce PDF files. Everything works properly, but problem is the time which CUPS-PDF printer needed to complete a job. For a PDF file with 25 pages CUPS-PDF need more than 5 min to produce new PDF file with 2 pages per side.
For the same job, program evince (print to file) need only few second to complete it.
What is the problem?

**EDIT**
/var/log/cups/error_log

```
D [03/Jan/2016:10:38:42 +0100] [Job 155] Running command line for gs: 
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOUTPUTFILE=%stdout
 -dLanguageLevel=2 -r600 -dCompress     Fonts=false -dNoT3CCITT -
dNOINTERPOLATE -c 'save pop' -f /tmp/00f93568f5865
```

Comment: What command are you using for cups-pdf ?

Comment: @Pandya lpr -P PDF  -o number-up=2 test.pdf

Comment: What are the resulting file sizes like? If CUPS' file is a lot larger, this might indicate that it renders a file that has bitmaps for each page.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz input file size 3.6MB , output file size is 19MB. but the same problem is for PDF files which were created with pdflatex. input file 1.1MB, output size is 12MB.

Comment: What does http://localhost:631/printers/PDF say?

Comment: Set CUPS to debug by changing `LogLevel` to `debug` in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`. Restart the cups service. Do a print to PDF and check the `/var/log/cups/error_log`. Try to find the line: *`Running command line for gs: gs ...`* then [edit] your post and add that line.

Comment: Tested `lpr -P PDF -o number-up=2 A.pdf`on a PDF document with 300 pages, and it was done after about 40 seconds - with 300 dpi. That was with *default* settings as found in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`. You might find something else interesting in the log as well ...

Comment: @Sukminder I added a Running command line for gs

Comment: @lobi: Sorry. Forgot about this. Your `-dCompress  Fonts=false` looks weird. Should be `-dCompressFonts=false` (Likely only a copy-paste thing). Beside that i notice you have 600dpi on resolution. That is rather high. Then again - how that affect relates to the content of the PDF. You *could* try to use 300dpi. Not sure how to do that from options on command line or `lpoptions`, but you can have a look at `/etc/cups/ppd/PDF.ppd` and change *DefaultResolution* to 300dpi. (Check in debug if this *really* changes it. Could be you have some setting in e.g. `~/.cups/...` that overrides this.)